# Should I register for Google Search Console even if my website builder platform has its own SEO tools?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I am with ionos.co.uk websites builder platform. They have some SEO tools intergrated. Should I also register for Google Search Console?

Comment: Google is a search engine you are targeting. Ionos is a web hosting company. What to do, what to do?

Comment: The question is,should I rely solely on Ionos, or should I also make my own optimization on the side?

Comment: I'd always register with the GSC, it has information you can't get from anywhere else.

Comment: Great, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9128668?hl=en), here are the features of Google Search Console:

- Confirm that Google can find and crawl your site.
- Fix indexing problems and request re-indexing of new or updated content.
- View Google Search traffic data for your site: how often your site appears in Google Search, which search queries show your site, how often searchers click through for those queries, and more.
- Receive alerts when Google encounters indexing, spam, or other issues on your site.
- Show you which sites link to your website.
- Troubleshoot issues for AMP, mobile usability, and other Search features.

To answer your question, if you want access to these features and your current tools don't provide them, then you should register for Google Search Console. If you do not need these features or your current tools provide them, then there is no need to register for Google Search Console.

It's worth noting that Google doesn't start collecting data for your website until you register, so if you think you might want access in the future, it could be useful to register now so that they start collecting data.

Answer (score 0):

Google search console is one of the best and FREE Google SEO tools you will find in the market because this one tool can tell you a lot about your website but you have to start analyzing with this SEO tool.

If you want to improve your google search ranking for your articles and website does google search console helps SEO. Because without Google Search Console your website will not be complete technically.